# PHP Docker install php7-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, docker, php-extension

For a while now, I'm trying to install the `php7-mysql` driver into different PHP docker containers from [php/docker](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/) with no luck.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:7.3-rc-apache-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

When I attach to the container and try to run

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Debian stretch says that it has no installation candidate.

> E: Package 'php7.0-mysql' has no installation candidate

What can I do to be able to install php7.0 modules to Debian Stretch?

Thanks in advance, this really took me some pomodores now!

Comment: Hey @divramod, did you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are missing the repository for php7.

- Adding the php7 ppa:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
- Then update:

  `sudo apt-get update`
- Now do a search to confirm php7 is there:

  `sudo apt search php7`
- Now install the php7 package:

  `sudo apt install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: I got this error: ```/bin/sh: 1: add-apt-repository: not found```

Comment: @HadiRasouli in this case, you'll need to install the command first:
`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Answer (score 0):

Did not work with ppa:ondrej/php but this works:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

You can also install php7.0 from there